# Why is Windows Guest VM running on VMWare Player 15 with Hyper-V mode on is super slow?

Tags: vmware, hyper-v, vmware-player

Why is Windows Guest VM running on VMWare Player 15 with Hyper-V mode on is super slow?

The host machine is Windows 10 with 4 CPU @ 3.2 GHz and 16 GB DDR4 memory installed.

Here's the link for the VMWare version I am using along with Hyper-V:
https://blogs.vmware.com/workstation/2020/05/vmware-workstation-now-supports-hyper-v-mode.html

Comment: Have you contacted VMWare with regards to the performance problems?  I have no experienced the same problems on my hardware.

Comment: @Ramhound do you have Hyper-V enabled on your machine?

Comment: Yes;  I absolutely have it enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound are you sure? Okay, do you have VMware tools installed in WIndows guest virtual machine?

Comment: I am absolutely positive, what I have enabled and installed on my machine, I have not noticed any performance issues with VMWare Workstation 15.5.5 on Windows 10 version 2004 with Hyper-V enabled.

Comment: I am using Windows XP and it is quite slow, Windows 7 is okay I just tested now